# Request variables as a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

One of the features I like most about [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is that I can specify query parameters as a dictionary:

```
r = requests.get('https://example.com/posts', params={
    'count': '12',
    'start': '56',
    'order': 'new'
})
```

I'm currently building a web scraper in Scrapy. Is there a way to specify a dictionary of query params rather than hardcoding everything into the url?

I'm currently being forced to do something like this:

```
scrapy.Request('https://example.com/posts?count=%d&start=%d&order=%s' %
    (12, 56, 'new',))
```

Is there a way to do what I want similar to the way that requests does it above?

Comment: You can apply basic string manipulation to write the string in the form of key, value pairs

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Updated the question: Python 2.7.

Comment: @ZdaR I'm aware of being able to do that. It's just nicer to not have to construct the `?...=...&...=...` string altogether.

Comment: @karthikr That doesn't help me with a GET request.

Answer (score 3):

```
from urllib import urlencode
params = {
    'count': '12',
    'start': '56',
    'order': 'new'
}
paramstr = urlencode(params) # 'count=12&start=56&order=new'
scrapy.Request('https://example.com/posts?' + paramstr)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `FormRequest` subclass of `scrapy.Request` provides that functionality with the `formdata` parameter:

```
import scrapy

class DemoSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'demo'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    def parse(self, response):

        request = scrapy.FormRequest(
            url = 'http://www.example.com',
            method = 'GET',
            formdata = {'count': '12', 'start': '56', 'order': 'new'},
            callback = self.parse
        )

        print request.url # http://www.example.com?count=12&start=56&order=new
        yield request
```

See the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-to-send-data-via-http-post) for Requests.

Comment: hi, would you mind giving ah help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630771/scrapy-linkextractor-duplicating/31634061#31634061